# it throws this error: Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I need help with this coding, i'm not sure what has happened.please don't duplicate this question or similar as I already tried any solution on the internet and nothing worked. I am trying to get "access to download URL after upload".

I attempted :I use the autocomplete of the metadata it shows no url option the closest I got was metadata.path or metadata.storageReference.

2nd attempt: I know The API had changed at version 5.0.0, so I use StorageReference's downloadURL method. that gives me an error too maybe I am putting it on the wrong line of code or else.

here is the class :-

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class SignUpVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var userImagePicker: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var userNameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var SignUpBtn: UIButton!

var userId: String!
var emailField: String!
var passwordField: String!
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
var imageselected = false
var userName: String!

//Do any Additional SetUp after  loading the view
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super .viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if let _ = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "uid") {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToMessges", sender: nil)
        }
    }
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage{
        userImagePicker.image = image
        imageselected = true
    }else{
        print("Image wasent selected!")
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
func setuser(img: String){
    let userData = [
        "username": userName!,"userimage": img]
    KeychainWrapper.standard.set(userId, forKey: "uid")
    let location = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId)
    location.setValue(userData)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func uploadImg (){
        if userNameField.text == nil {
            SignUpBtn.isEnabled = false

        }else {
            userName = userNameField.text
            SignUpBtn.isEnabled = true
        }

        guard let img = userImagePicker.image, imageselected == true else {
            print("Image needs to be selected")

            return
        }

        if let imgData = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) {

            let imgUid = NSUUID().uuidString
            let metadata = StorageMetadata()
            metadata.contentType = "image/Jpeg"
            Storage.storage().reference().child(imgUid).putData(imgData, metadata:metadata){(metaData,error
                ) in

                if error != nil {
                print("Did not upload Image!")

            }else {
                   print("Uploaded")

                    let downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL()?.absoulteString      //error here 

                    if let url = downloadURL {
                        self.setUser(img:url)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Surely one [of these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=StorageMetadata%27+has+no+member+%27downloadURL%27) will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it didn’t work that’s why I posed it . It would be easy if you help instead of put it on duplicate. SMH

Comment: Your question shows no attempt to resolve the issue so it is a duplicate as it stands. And "didn't work" is an insufficient description of a problem. Update your question with what attempts you made and clearly indicate in what way they didn't work.

Comment: I made some changes on my question hope this clears up the confusion.

Comment: Please take the time to properly format your code. Make sure it looks correct in the preview before submitting.

Comment: Sir ! I will fix my format on my Xcode but right now am Worrying about my error not about my format. anyway if you are not willing to help . you can just leave it that . thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Firebase [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageMetadata#dictionaryrepresentation), you may there is no direct property `downloadURL` in `StorageMetadata` class. So you may have to use `dictionaryRepresentation` and access download link using [mediaLink](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource) key.

Example:

```
if let downloadURL = metadata.dictionaryRepresentation()["mediaLink"] as? String{

     self.setUser(img:downloadURL)
}
```

Comment: And if we use ["mediaLink"] I think Firebase does the rest right? I don't think we need to change and database labels. It looks that way.